# T-SQL Where int=@var / @var=null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, integer

I am having a situation where I call a stored procedure and pass in some variables.  In some cases i will be passing in null and I want it to return everything.  Take the following (age is an Integer column):

```
[Table]  
[Name] | [Age]  
Mike   | 22  
Fred   | 18  
Bob    | 22 



SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [Age]=@AgeVar
```

Now if I pass in 22 I will get Mike and Bob. Similarly passing in 18 will get me Fred.  However, What if I want all 3 rows when I pass in null/don't set @AgeVar?  This is my issue on a very simple scale.

Edit: The Sproc is pretty complex and i don't really want to double all the sections up by having to but them twice as in one of the answers below. Are there any other methods?

Comment: Read [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: If you don't have time to click on Joe's link to his very excellent article, he demonstrates that using dynamic SQL may very well outperform this approach.

Comment: @DOK: Just to be clear, I am not the author of the article. That article was written by Gail Shaw, who is much smarter than I am regarding SQL Server.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, we are all standing on the shoulders of giants, aren't we?

Comment: Please stop signing your posts.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [Age]=@AgeVar OR @AgeVar IS NULL
```

As mentioned numerous times above and below, this technique will kill the performance of your queries for large tables.  User beware.

Comment: That's a Brilliant answer. never thought of doing it that way round. Brilliant.  I'll mark it as an answer in a little while as it says i've got to what. But Thanks!!

Comment: JUST FYI... this plays havoc with the Query Execution Plans in SqlServer... we recently had to refactor a bunch of SPROC because of queries like the above.

Comment: @EoinCampbell: That is the point of the blog post I cited in my comment on the question.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, but it is definitely a performance killer. No matter what, though, when the requirements specifies this behavior, your options are limited. This is particularly true when binding a report to an individual query or stored procedure.

Comment: To be honest I think the performance killer is more the DB design than anything. This query might not help but i'm fairly confident solving my issues there would make the need for this style query go away :(.  Best learn more about db design and indices..

Answer (score 3):

```
IF @AgeVar IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @Table
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @Table
        WHERE   Age = @AgeVar
    END
```

Comment: Yeah, I was considering something like this but the Stored Procedure i'm doing this in is pretty huge and dont really want to segment each section into two parts just for this.  Is there any other way?

Comment: The `OR` option already posted would work, as would `WHERE ISNULL(@AgeVar, [Age]) = [Age]`. However the option posted above is dealt with better by the optimiser. You could consider creating a temp table, filling it using `IF ... ELSE` then refering to that later in the procedure, but this could work out worse depending on the rest of the procedure and indicies etc.

Comment: I would be concerned about query plan caching with this one.

Comment: I would be less concerned about the query caching than I would the performace impact of using unnessearry predicates in the select statement. To solve the problem the OP posted this is the most efficient solution. If further variables are required then SQL Injection is probably the way forward as discussed in other comments/articles.

Comment: @GarethD I think you meant dynamic SQL, not SQL injection. Unless your intentions are less than honorable and SQL injection is a given! :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I certainly did mean Dunamic SQL, hopefully that is not a Freudian slip, and I do not have some dark alter ego waiting to play havoc with people's dynamic SQL queries... That comment was made 2 minutes before leaving work and I will attribute it to carelessness and excitement, not malice (on this occassion). Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you have a common case, then use a CASE statement. This will make the performance drag only in the rare case. So, if you more often pass a null in as the parameter, then this will be more efficient.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table] 
WHERE 
    0 = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @AgeVar IS NULL THEN 0
            WHEN [Age]=@AgeVar THEN 0
        END
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested this but it seems to me that this won't work: If [Age] = @AgeVar then the final query will end up looking like

select * from [table] where 0=0

...and you'll end up getting ALL the records!

Comment: I have used this to great success in numerous cases. Think about how SQL works, and this should make sense. It is similar to an exists. The select * from [table] where 0 = 0 only occurs for the case where the current row being evaluated's [Age] column is equal to @AgeVar. By your logic, anytime any match in SQL is made at all, then all records would return

Answer (score 1):

This will give you MUCH better performance than the `[Age]=@AgeVar OR @AgeVar IS NULL` method, because it will generate index seeks instead of index scans:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1]
WHERE COALESCE(@AgeVar, Age) = Age
```

It leaves your code fairly readable, especially when you have multiple parameters that you may or may not be using to search, and still gives you reasonable performance.